# rails habtm relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 models which have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I want to know how can I get a category name through this relation, for example I find a first template:

```
t = Template.find(:first)
```

Then using `t.categories` will return an object, but I want to have category.name in return, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is a template supposed to have one category or many categories in your domain?

Comment: it can have one or many categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the names of the categories associated with your first `Template` instance, you can do:

```
Template.first.categories.collect(&:name)
```

—This uses the `Symbol#to_proc` support that Rails adds. More information in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/6-shortcut-blocks-with-symbol-to-proc).

Comment: can i create a link for each of these items in this way ?
how can i put some space between each item ?
thnx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
t.categories.first.name
```

Comment: That only gets you the name of the first category associated with the template. I believe the OP wants the name of all the categories.

Comment: But he says "I want to get a category name" not category names. I think he may not be understanding the many part of habtm.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that a category record has the name field you can do:

```
t.categories.map(&:name)
```

Comment: whats the different between map and collect methods ?

Comment: they are the same, name aliases only.